# rails asynchronous communication and xhr polling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, long-polling

I need to write a Rails application (JRuby) that does asynchronous communication with another service in the background. There needs to be one connection per browser session. (It does not really need to be a open TCP connection but I need to free resources after the session ends.) The communication with the background service is not strict request - response. At any time there can be a message sent from the service to the rails app.

I also need to implement the protocol. How do I do this? Is there a asynchronous framework (e.g. like Twisted or Node.js) for Ruby on Rails? I just need some starting points.

I already wrote a quick implementation of the client side protocol in Python. In fact the complete protocol is made up by me (the server is written in JavaScript), so I could change the protocol completely. However, the asynchronous nature cannot be changed because of the nature of the problem.

Also I need XHR polling/WebSockets in order to push the async changes to the browser. Is there a gem/howto/tutorial for that? I can't just set the request to sleep (resources!).

In case you want to know more about the background:
The Rails application is a accessibility tool. The service with which it communicates is actually a Firefox Add-on that loads and renders webpages. The asynchronous nature comes from (i)frames, popup windows (`window.open()`, `window.alert()`, ...), dynamic changes to the DOM tree that have to be communicated to the Rails app, redirects (like after posing in a forum) etc. I need to use JRuby because I need to use the Jena (Java) framework for RDF processing.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby On Rails is an asynchronous framework too. with a thin server. Node.js or Twisted are not a Asynchrone framework. There just Event framework.

In ruby the Event Framework is EventMachine and thin serveur use it. You can create some websocket with a rack::middleware and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Juggernaut 2](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut), it does exactly this (and it also uses node).  I am using it to push messages from my server to all connected clients and it works great.  Implementation was a breeze (although the readme is a bit unclear on certain things), lemme know if you need any help with it.

Comment: That looks like it might be what I need. Thanks.